# Can't Change Color of Single Side

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to make a Rubik's Cube, but when I change the color of one Cube's Face, all of the cube's colors change. [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Answer (score 1):

You *can* control the colors a single material has, per face, in various procedural ways, or you can UV map your object, and its material can refer to a texture map, assigning colors in any way you like, across the surfaces of your object.

But here, you probably want to assign separate *materials* to each face.

- Click the '+' sign next to the materials list currently showing 'Material', highlighted. This will create a new slot.
- Press 'New' below the list, to create a new material, or select a material you have already created, from the dropdown accessible just to the left of that button.
- If the material is 'New', give it the color/ other characteristics you want.
- With the desired material active in the list, and the desired faces selected in Edit Mode, hit 'Assign'. The selected faces will acquire the selected material.